# forge.js Replicate what I do with rsa but with aes

Tags: javascript, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

Im using the JavaScript library forge.js (https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge)

rsa publicKey if 896 bits in length lets me encrypt a fare bit of text but, the length of the publicKey it's self is too long for my needs.

If I shorten it to a key of 460 bits then the length of the key is almost ok but, I then am limited to only encrypting a short amount.

I like the features of RSA (encrypt/decrypt & sign/verify) but I don't like the length of the key it's self and the limit on size.

Is there another form of encryption that would be better suited for my use?

needs:

- A public key about 20 characters long
- to be able to encrypt around 140 characters
- same or similar features as RSA

I have been playing around with forge AES but it looks like the encryption is sort of a shared thing - You have your one key (that is shared?). then you can create a cypher and decypher. But I don't see how this would work similar to rsa as; with rsa I can share my publicKey and be safe to sign and decrypt but I don't see how I can do the same with my current understanding of aes.

How I currently would opperate:

```
//make sure that what user has said both hasn't been tampered with and is for you
var kp=forge.pki.rsa.generateKeyPair({bits: 896,e:0x10001});
var m=['Hi!'];
m[1]=kp.privateKey.sign(forge.md.sha1.create().update(m[0],'utf8'));
console.log(m);
console.log(kp.publicKey.verify(forge.md.sha1.create().update(m[0],'utf8').digest().bytes(),m[1]));
var asked='did you read this?';
var ask=kp.publicKey.encrypt(asked);
var read=kp.privateKey.decrypt(ask);
var r=['yes!'];
console.log('yes?');
r[1]=kp.privateKey.sign(forge.md.sha1.create().update(r[0],'utf8'));
r[2]=kp.privateKey.sign(forge.md.sha1.create().update(read,'utf8'));
console.log(kp.publicKey.verify(forge.md.sha1.create().update(asked,'utf8').digest().bytes(),r[2]));
```

Note: You would need do the decrypt and verify with `try{}catch(e){}` in production just incase the messages we're for a different users publicKey.

So far I can encrypt and decrypt REALLY basicly but I don't understand how to turn this form of cyrptography into what I am used to

```
//encypher the letter i then decypher it
var aes=forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2('k9','kr',1000,32);
var ci=forge.cipher.createCipher('AES-CBC',aes);
ci.start({'iv':'k5'});
ci.update(forge.util.createBuffer('i','utf8'));
ci.finish();
console.log(ci.output.toHex());
var ci=forge.cipher.createDecipher('AES-CBC',aes);
ci.start({'iv':'k5'});
ci.update(forge.util.createBuffer(forge.util.hexToBytes('7276131d61a323c37b5e451c3acc983e')));
ci.finish();
ci.output.toString('utf8')
//7276131d61a323c37b5e451c3acc983e
//"i"

// k9 kr k5 might as well just be me mashing the keyboard with my head btw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you can't use AES as a replacement of RSA, because as you already noted, then AES key must be shared.

A 460 bit RSA key doesn't provide (any) security nowadays. It can be brute-forced with a little bit of EC2 time. The recommendation would be to use at least 2048 bit RSA keys.

Since you want to sign stuff, you can use ECDSA which is based on Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC) and enables you to use much smaller keys for similar security ([Some numbers](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3216/signatures-rsa-compared-to-ecdsa)). Forge doesn't provide [ECC support](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/116) yet.

[SJCL](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl) provides an implementation of ECDSA

- Add sjcl.js, core/bn.js, core/ecc.js
- Generate keys `var ecdsaKeys = sjcl.ecc.ecdsa.generateKeys(256);`
- `ecdsaKeys.pub` provides the [`verify()` function](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.ecc.ecdsa.publicKey.html#verify)
- `ecdsaKeys.sec` provides the [`sign()` function](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/symbols/sjcl.ecc.ecdsa.secretKey.html#sign)
- If you need to send the public or secret key, then you need to serialize it yourself.

---

If you need encryption instead of signature, use ElGamal instead of ECDSA. SJCL also provides that. Since it is impossible to encrypt 140 characters with any size of ElGamal keys, you would need to opt in for a [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) with AES. SJCL also provides that with some authenticated modes like GCM or CCM.